# How to check in cypress if element is visible on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chai, cypress

I have a web page which is very long and there is a footer on the bottom. To see the footer I have to scroll down. I want to write a cypress test to make sure that the footer is not visible when a user is on the top of the page. To do that I write such code:

```
        cy
        .get('#footer')
        .should('not.be.visible')
```

And it fails although it is in fact not on the screen, but below the visible part of the page.

Answer (score 10):

The assertion `be.visible` [is designed to](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/877#issuecomment-342190597) check if the user is able to interact with an element *even if she has to scroll down to it.*

But you can add and use a custom assertion `isInViewport`, have a look at https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/877#issuecomment-490504922.

Comment: The custom command at that ^^ link works perfectly for what I needed